# A question on Hartshorne Exercise II.6.11 - what is the structure sheaf of an effective divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to solve this exercise, but it contains a definition that I don't really understand. I wonder if you could explain it explicitly.

In this exercise, $X$ is a nonsingular curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, and $K(X)$ is the Grothendieck group of $X$. In part (a), $D=\sum_i P_i$ is a divisor on $X$. Then he says :"If $D$ is effective, let $\mathcal O_D$ be the structure sheaf of the associated subscheme of codimension 1." I really don't know how to get such a $\mathcal O_D$ from the definition of $D$, could you explain it for me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In very general terms, an effective Cartier divisor is one which has a representation $\{(U_i,f_i)\}$ for $\{U_i\}$ an open cover of $X$ and $f_i\in\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$. Because $f_i/f_j$ is a unit on $U_i\cap U_j$, we can glue the closed subschemes $V(f_i)\subset U_i$ together to a closed subscheme $D$, and the structure sheaf of this is what you want.

In terms much more specific to your problem, suppose we can write $D=\sum n_iP_i$ for finitely many points $P_i$ with each $n_i>0$. Then for each $P_i$, let $t_i$ be a uniformizer for the DVR $\mathcal{O}_{X,P_i}$. The sheaf $\mathcal{O}_D$ is then the direct sum of the sheaves $(\iota_i)_*(\mathcal{O}_{X,P_i}/t_i^{n_i})$, where $\iota_i:\{P_i\}\to X$ is the inclusion of the point $P_i$.